# How do I deploy maven dependencies in a web application project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, jsp, intellij-idea, glassfish

I followed [these steps on JetBrain's site](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/enabling-web-application-support.html) to create a web application and get GlassFish going locally. It runs fine, I can embed output from code in the src tree of the project in the JSP and see it in the web browser. The problem starts when I add a Maven dependency. I added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>4.9</version>
</dependency>
```

to my pom.xml and use the dependency in my code. Maven installs the dependency, everything builds fine, but when I click the green arrow to run it in GlassFish I get this error when the browser opens:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   cannot access com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.SerializeException
>     class file for com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.SerializeException not found

Here's the source for index.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="com.idsrvjpoc.IdentityServerConfiguration" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Redirect</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% String redirectUrl = new IdentityServerConfiguration().getRedirectUrl(); %>
        <a href="<%=redirectUrl%>"><%=redirectUrl%></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the Java Compiler settings for my module the target bytecode version is set to 1.8 and I'm using the latest version of the 1.8 JDK.

I found another SO answer that suggested copying the dependencies' JAR files to the glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib folder, so I tried that and it changed the error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/oauth2/sdk/id/ClientID

No more obsolete target value or class file not found, but a NoClassDefFoundError. It's a different class now. Both SerializeException and ClientID are in the same JAR, and I can extract the JAR and see both the .class files in what appear to me to be the correct places.

Here's the source for IdentityServerConfiguration.java:

```
package com.idsrvjpoc;

import com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.*;
import com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.id.*;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class IdentityServerConfiguration {
    public String getRedirectUrl() throws URISyntaxException, SerializeException {
        URI authzEndpoint = new URI("myAuthEndpoint");
        ClientID clientID = new ClientID("1234");
        Scope scope = new Scope("openid");
        URI callback = new URI("http://localhost:8080/IdentityServerPoc_war_exploded/return.jsp");
        State state = new State();

        AuthorizationRequest request = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
                new ResponseType(ResponseType.Value.CODE), clientID).
                scope(scope).
                state(state).
                redirectionURI(callback).
                endpointURI(authzEndpoint).
                build();

        return request.toURI().toString();        
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

E: I just tried deleting the JARs from the GlassFish lib folder and editing the war artifact, on the Output Layout tab I moved the jars from the Available Elements to the WEB-INF/lib directory and I see that they get copied there when I build, but still the same error.

I also tried having the artifact extract the .class files from the JARs into the WEB-INF/classes folder. Again, I see them in the WEB-INF/classes folder in the out folder of my project, but still the same `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/oauth2/sdk/id/ClientID`

E2: Here is the complete pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>IdSrvJPoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>IdentityServerJavaPoc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Post your POM. Note that if you are manually setting the Java version in IDEA, that's not authoritative, and you need to do that in the POM. Additionally, you need to make sure that your runtime dependencies are getting packaged into your war.

Comment: Thanks! I edited in the POM. For the war, I'm pretty sure they're getting in there. I know for sure they're in the exploded war, which I think is all that is being used by the app server (although I'm far from certain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you get a NoClassDefFoundError there might still be depedencies missing in your lib folder. Make sure any Numbus dependencies are included as well.